# Rselenium specifying directory of chrome driver

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to run Rselenium but the package is unable to find my `chromedriver.exe`.

My working directory is my `Documents` folder and I have `chromedriver.exe` in the folder. But it still is unable to find it. It keeps looking in a temporary folder.

```
> library(RSelenium)
> driver<- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, platvec, value = switch(Sys.info()["sysname"],  : 
  no such index at level 1
```

So then I used

```
startServer(args = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/Users/Jessica/Documents/chromedriver.exe")) 

Error: startServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function in
    file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
    recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
    see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.
```

But got a deprecation error. Apparantly the function does not work anymore.

How do I specify the location of the `chromedriver.exe`? The function `rsDriver()` does not have any options to place it in there.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way of running selenium? Have you tried using [Docker](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html), which is the recommended way? I know installing it on Windows can be a bit of a hassle, but I would really recommend you take this route.

Comment: A few things, one, you might want to try re-installing `RSelenium`, your error message makes it look like a library path isn't mapping correctly. Two, like @RomanLuštrik suggests, using Docker is the preferred way to run RSelenium now. Three, if you do choose to use `rsDriver` instead, make sure the Chrome Driver version matches the version of your Chrome browser. For me, `rsDriver` defaulted to the V77 driver, and I had V76 of the Chrome browser. I had to manually select the V76 driver to get it to run.

Comment: It's not a version mismatch, I have gotton that error message before and it not this. This error message is a result of not being able to find the chrome driver in general. And why is Docker a prefered method? Sounds like I have to go through an intermediary to be able to access Rselenium rather than using my own computer to be able to use. Docker is a 3rd party website.

Comment: Docker is virtualization software that lets you run Selenium in a very controlled, version stable environment. In the RSelenium use case for Docker, you're running a Docker container on `localhost`, and then sending commands to the container via R. It's all running locally on your computer, although you do have to download and install Docker, plus an R selenium image.

Comment: As to "why is Docker a preferred method", I'll quote the RSelenium/Docker vignette: "Running a docker container standardises the build across OS’s and removes many of the issues user may have relating to JAVA/browser version/selenium version etc."

Comment: What does `binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")` give you for output?

Comment: `> binman::list_versions("seleniumserver")
$generic
[1] "3.12.0"        "3.13.0"        "3.14.0"        "3.141.0"       "3.141.5"       "3.141.59"     
[7] "4.0.0-alpha-1" "4.0.0-alpha-2"`

Comment: Have you tried deleting `RSelenium` and re-installing like I suggested before? I can't reproduce your issue, so it seems likely it has something to do with your local library/R configuration.

Comment: Like everyone said, that method is deprecated. It's easy to install docker, reboot (NECESSARY after installing docker), download/run a selnium instance on your computer inside a docker container, and connect R. If you must use the old method you might try installing an older version of RSelenium instead of the new version.

Comment: Have you tried running the the server separately from cmd. I haven't used Windows for a while but last I remember you could start a server instance with `java -jar` followed by the `-Dwebdriver` argument and other parameters in the relevant directory

Comment: from the rselenium github page: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar`... More at https://ropensci.github.io/RSelenium/articles/basics.html#introduction